# Using LineNumberReader Class to display line/word/#line

Tags: java, line-numbers

We are suppose to create a method that 
•   The number of lines in the file
•   The number of words in the file, and 
•   The number of characters in the file excluding blanks. 
i.e File:  xxx.txt has 120 lines, 317 words, 4154 characters

•   Search the file line by line for a given string. The output must contain the line number followed by the contents of the line that contains the search argument. For instance given the following as input string:  Java, where Java is the search string the output would be something like this:

5:  on the island of Java

9:  The people of JAVA loves jaVa.

Use the class LineNumberReader for this exercise

I am having a difficult time. I keep getting an I/O error saying stream closed when I am running my code.

This is my code. I have the part of lines, words, characters. But I can't get the second part to work

```
public String wordCount()
{
    try
    {
        int wordCount = 0,
            numberCount = 0,
            lineCount = 1,
            characterCount = 0;

        String c = " "; 

        FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(r);
        StreamTokenizer t = new StreamTokenizer(r);
        ArrayList <String> results = new ArrayList<String>();


        t.resetSyntax();
        t.whitespaceChars(0, ' ');
        t.wordChars('a','z');
        t.wordChars('A','Z');
        t.wordChars('0','9');

        t.eolIsSignificant(true);

        while(t.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF)
        {
            switch(t.ttype)
            {
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                numberCount++;
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                characterCount += t.sval.length();
                wordCount++;
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
                lineCount++;
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                break;
                default:

            }
        }

        r.close();
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt"));
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
    int recCount = 0;
    String record = null;
       while ((record = bf.readLine()) != null) {
          recCount++;
          out.write(recCount + ": " + record);
          out.newLine();
       }
    out.close();


    String ask = "Enter Word";

String find = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ask);
String word = find;


while(lnr.readLine() != null )
    {
        String line = lnr.readLine();
        if (line.indexOf(word) >= 0)
        {
            results.add(lnr.getLineNumber() + line);
        }
    } 
    lnr.close();


       String str = f.getName() + " has " +  lineCount + " line(s), " +
                 wordCount + " word(s), " +
                 characterCount  + " characters. " + "\n These lines contain"
               + "the word in search of:" ;
       for(int index=0; index<results.size();index++)
       {
           if(results !=null)
           {
               str+= results.get(index) + "\n";
           }
        }

     return str;
    }
```

I notice it breaks around the this part of code. If I comment the code out it works minus the part I am trying to do.

```
String ask = "Enter Word";

String find = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ask);
String word = find;


while(lnr.readLine() != null )
    {
        String line = lnr.readLine();
        if (line.indexOf(word) >= 0)
        {
            results.add(lnr.getLineNumber() + line);
        }
    } 
lnr.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

In your loop

```
while(lnr.readLine() != null )
```

You try to read from `lnr`, which relies on `r`, which you closed earlier.

Solution: do not close `r` before you are done with the file completely.  Since you want to open the file again, the easiest way would be to move the above loop right before the `r.close()` as the loop does not depend on results from `out`.

Also, when you write

```
while(lnr.readLine() != null)
{
  String line = lnr.readLine();
```

You are skipping lines (you read one in the loop condition, which is discarded, then you read the next line into `line`. You could do this instead:

```
String line = null;
while((line = lnr.readLine()) != null)
{
  // rest of the loop
```

this will read the next line, assign it to `line` and check for `null` every time the loop is executed

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that I had put the r.close at the top.
Now I can't get the second part that I am trying to accomplish to work. Nothing is displaying from the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that the line

```
r.close();
```

is closing your handle on the file. So when you try and read from it later on, you can't see into it anymore. Try deleting that close.

**Edit:**
See Attila's more detailed answer :)